# Scala, ZIO - how to convert Unit into ZIO[Any, Nothing, Unit] after iterating all elements in list?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, zio

I have a simple method:

```
def process(element: SomeData): ZIO[Any, Nothing, Unit]
```

I would like to use it on every element from list:

```
def processElements(list: List[SomeData]): ZIO[Any, Nothing, Unit] = {
  list.foreach(element => 
    process(element)
  )
}
```

And this method returns `Unit`, so I added `ZIO.succeed()`:

```
def processElements(list: List[SomeData]): ZIO[Any, Nothing, Unit] = {
      ZIO.succeed(list.foreach(element => 
        process(element)
      ))
    }
```

I am not sure if it good approach to do it. Is it possible that this code will not be done or return errors? Is there better way to convert `Unit` into `ZIO[Any, Nothing, Unit]`?
Also I am not sure if this `foreach` method is ok to use here, but I have no idea how I should process all elements from list in other way.

Comment: You want what is called `traverse_` but since **ZIO** believes that using standard names is bad because you need to study like two hours to understand it, they provide this functionality under a more familiar name `foreach_` but AFAIK they do not provide it as an extension method on collections but rather as a helper method on the `ZIO` object, so your final code would be: `ZIO.foreach_(list)(process)`